# how to get javascript function's returned value in fancybox2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I have a link something like this

```
<a onclick="returnCategory($(this).attr('data-category-id'))" data-category-id="15">Tablets</a>
```

and the function called using onclick is

```
function returnCategory(categoryId) {
    return categoryId;
}
```

my fancybox code is

```
function showPopup() {
    $.fancybox({
        href: 'popup.php',
        type: 'ajax',
        width: '90%',
        height: '100%',
        beforeClose : function () {
            categoryId = returnCategory();
            alert("Required category Id is :" + categoryId);
        },
    });
}
```

Clicking on the anchor the above code generates an alert "**Required category Id is : undefined**"

My question is how to alert the value returned by returnCategory() function in fancybox beforeClose?
I don't want to use global variable here.

Comment: When is the `showPopup()` function being triggered? ... then the `returnCategory()` function is expecting a parameter so if you do inside the callback `categoryId = returnCategory()` how are you expecting to get a value without passing a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the function `returnCategory` returns the value that was passed to it. So when you call it in fancybox beforeClose event without passing a parameter it will return `undefined`. If you really can't user global variables one way of doing it is with hidden inputs like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="selectedCategory"/>
```

and the javascript

```
function returnCategory(categoryId) {
var inputCategory = document.getElementById("selectedCategory");
inputCategory.value = categoryId;
}
```

and

```
beforeClose:function(){

selectedCategoryId = document.getElementById("selectedCategory").value;
alert("Required category Id is :" + selectedCategoryId );
}
```